# How to integrate imgui to an SDL2 + OpenGL project

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, codeblocks, sdl-2

I want to use imgui in my SDL2 project, but I have absolutely no clue how to implement it. I copied the files from the github link, added a folder called "imgui"  and within it there are some headers. the "imgui.h" header is recognized, but it seems to be missing `#include "imgui/imgui_impl_sdl.h"`. I am trying to follow this tutorial https://marcelfischer.eu/blog/2019/imgui-in-sdl-opengl/#fn-imgui-backends but its very confusing. I don't know what/how to integrate "cmake" nor what the cmake file is, or what the name of the cmake file is, or how to add it to my `codeblocks` project. Is all the code from the "cmake" instructions part of the cmake file? What does this mean?

```
Now we can add it as dependency to our main target prog like this:

target_link_libraries(prog imgui)
```

do I have to name my codeblocks project "prog" or "imgui"?

Comment: You don't need CMake. You just have to compile some ImGui `.cpp` files as a part of your project. You need all `.cpp` files in the root directory, and also `backends/...sdl` and `backends/...opengl2` (OR `opengl3`).

Comment: I tried to put all of them in the same directory but files in a folder within it (for example the SDL2 ones) gave me an error with "imgui file not found" because the directory was "imgui.h" yet that isn't in that directory.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it doesn't make sense to me that the files that aren't in the same directory use the same syntax for `#include`?

Comment: If you move the .cpp files, you should also move the corresponding .h files. OR you could just set include search paths without moving anything.